# Не получается вывести ответ с конструкцией if и break

Tags: javascript, if

Суть задания заключается в том, чтобы принять значение возраста через метод prompt, а затем вывести строку с нужным падежом для этого самого числа.
В коде присутствует операнд %, который, по идее должен считывать остаток от деления на 10 и выводил нужную информацию. Помимо этого я использовал конструкцию break для того, чтобы браузер не выводил сообщение <Вам 'неправильный возраст' лет>, а затем говорил, что произошла ошибка. Но, к сожалению, я что-то добавил лишнего и теперь браузер не выводит ничего

```js
let age;
age = prompt('Введите число, не превышающее 120...');
while (age !== "" && age > 0 && typeof (age) == "number") {
    if (age % 10 === 0) {
        document.write('<b>' + 'Вам ' + '</b>' + '<b>' + 'лет' + '</b>');
    }
    if (age % 2 === 0 && age / 3 === 0) {
        document.write('<b>' + 'Вам ' + '</b>' + '<b>' + 'года' + '</b>');
    }
    if (age % 2 === 1) {
        document.write('<b>' + 'Вам ' + '</b>' + '<b>' + 'год' + '</b>');
    } else {
        if (age < 0) {
            document.write("Возраст не может быть меньше нуля!");
            break;
        }
        if (typeof(age) !== "number") {
            document.write('<b>' + 'Это не число!' + '</b>');
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: `'age'` это строка. А `age` это переменная с введенным значением.

Comment: По-прежнему не работает, ошибка где-то в другом месте

Comment: Да тут везде сплошные ошибки...

Comment: Я это понимаю, я поэтому и прошу помочь

Comment: Ну так займитесь дебагом. Выясните - срабатывает ли `while`. Если нет - то почему. И далее.

Comment: Задача элементарная, проблема элементарная - карандаш-блокнот-дебаггер в руки и вперед.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/2uht05jp/8/

```js
function num2str(n, text_forms) {  
        n = Math.abs(n) % 100; var n1 = n % 10;
        if (n > 10 && n < 20) { return text_forms[2];     }
        if (n1 > 1 && n1 < 5) { return text_forms[1];     }
        if (n1 == 1) { return text_forms[0]; }
        return text_forms[2];
}
try {
  let age;
  age = parseInt(prompt('Введите число, не превышающее 120...'))
  
  if(age < 0 || age > 120 || isNaN(age)) {
   document.write('Вы ввели неверное значение!')
  } else {
   document.write('Вам ' + age + ' '+num2str(age, ['год', 'года', 'лет']))
 }
} catch(e) {
 console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: Опять этот parseInt :(

Answer (score 0):

Не срабатывает, так как у вас в условии стоит `typeof (age) == "number"`, а вы вводите строку... И, соответственно, так же работает и условие `if (typeof(age) !== "number") {`

```js
let age;
age = prompt('Введите число, не превышающее 120...');
while (age !== "" && age > 0 && typeof (age) == "string") {
    if (age % 10 === 0) {
        document.write('<b>' + 'Вам ' + '</b>' + '<b>' + 'лет' + '</b>');
    }
    if (age % 2 === 0 && age / 3 === 0) {
        document.write('<b>' + 'Вам ' + '</b>' + '<b>' + 'года' + '</b>');
    }
    if (age % 2 === 1) {
        document.write('<b>' + 'Вам ' + '</b>' + '<b>' + 'год' + '</b>');
    } else {
        if (age < 0) {
            document.write("Возраст не может быть меньше нуля!");
            break;
        }
        if (typeof(age) !== "number") {
            document.write('<b>' + 'Это не число!' + '</b>');
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Если нужно число - возвращайте число через `parseInt()`

Comment: А, вот оно как было... Спасибо огромное)